# Split multiple columns by numeric or alphabetic symbols

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, split

I'm working on splitting multiple columns by numeric or alphabetic symbols for columns `v1` to `v3`, then take the first part as the values of this column. For example, `红岗花园12栋110房` will be split by `12` then take `红岗花园`, `德福花园德福豪苑C4栋C5栋C4座1403房` will be splited by `C4` and take `德福花园德福豪苑`.

```
    id       v1                      v2                     v3
0    1      泥岗路             红岗花园12栋110房                    NaN
1    2     沙井街道                     万丰路                     东侧
2    3      中心区                    N15区          幸福·海岸10栋A座11A
3    4      龙岗镇                     南联村       长海雅园2栋D301D302房产
4    5    蛇口工业区                     兴华路  海滨花园多层海滨花园兰山楼06栋504房产
5    6      宝安路         松园·南九巷综合楼10栋103                    NaN
6    7      宝安路         松园·南九巷综合楼10栋203                    NaN
7    8      龙岗镇                     中心城            尚景华园12栋307房
8    9     沙河西路            西博海名苑1栋30C房产                    NaN
9   10  华侨城香山中路              天鹅堡三期P栋4D房                    NaN
10  11      布吉镇  德福花园德福豪苑C4栋C5栋C4座1403房                    NaN
```

The code I have tried:

```
cols = ['v1', 'v2', 'v3']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: ''.join(re.compile(r'(\d+|\w+)')[0], x.str))
```

Output:

```
TypeError: ("'_sre.SRE_Pattern' object is not subscriptable", 'occurred at index v1')
```

My desired output will like this:

```
    id       v1         v2             v3
0    1      泥岗路       红岗花园            NaN
1    2     沙井街道        万丰路             东侧
2    3      中心区        NaN          幸福·海岸
3    4      龙岗镇        南联村           长海雅园
4    5    蛇口工业区        兴华路  海滨花园多层海滨花园兰山楼
5    6      宝安路  松园·南九巷综合楼            NaN
6    7      宝安路  松园·南九巷综合楼            NaN
7    8      龙岗镇        中心城           尚景华园
8    9     沙河西路      西博海名苑            NaN
9   10  华侨城香山中路      天鹅堡三期            NaN
10  11      布吉镇   德福花园德福豪苑            NaN
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does it mean you only want to remove all text after the first chunk of Chinese chars in Column v2? Or extract all text up to a non-Chinese char in that column?

Comment: Yes, split by first numbers or alphabets, then take the first chunk of Chinese chars for `v1, v2, v3`.

Comment: Try `df['v2'] = df['v1'].str.replace(r'[A-Za-z0-9].*', '')`, `df['v2'] = df['v2'].str.replace(r'[A-Za-z0-9].*', '')` and `df['v2'] = df['v3'].str.replace(r'[A-Za-z0-9].*', '')`

Comment: It works, thank you. You may answer with `cols = ['v1', 'v2', 'v3']; df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(r'[A-Za-z0-9].*', ''))` if you like, I'll accept.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to edit col names on the left side in my previous comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may remove all text after the first ASCII alphanumeric character in the columns you need to modify:

```
cols = ['v1', 'v2', 'v3']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(r'[A-Za-z0-9].*', ''))
```

If your columns can contain multiline texts, use

```
r'(?s)[A-Za-z0-9].*'
```

where `(?s)` inline modifier will let `.` match line break chars, too.